# newbie question: Do I need SQL Server Express (or Access) installed in order to read database?

Tags: sql-server

I'm learning to work with ASP.net and am starting to work with databases and have a general question.  I already have Access and SQL Server Express 2008 installed on my computer and have no issues adding sample databases to my programs; however, I was wondering if I would be able to open those databases in visual studio if I did not have those programs installed.

Also, if I made a program that was based on an Access or SQL Server database (like say an accounting program), would my users need to have those programs installed?  If so, how can I make a program that has an internal database without requiring the users to have those programs?

I know these are very general questions but if you could just give me a few keywords to look up, I would appreciate it.  I have a C and C++ background and my SQL background only made as far as creating databases and doing query gymnastics for my database professors so I have no clue how they work in real life.

Answer (score 0):

1.You Need Database to Create any Applications with CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete) functions.

2.If Your Application(Published as Installer(.exe)) is Stand-Alone or Only 1(PC/User) will use your Application you need to install Database Server on it.

1. [client Server architecture](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/client-server/client-server-architecture.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition - SP1 and above([SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)) if you want your database to be able to work without any installation

The "Private File based Deployment" section on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(VS.80).aspx) describes just how to achieve that.

You can also check out [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341861/sql-server-ce-is-an-installation-required-as-opposed-to-just-a-dll-include) for more details. 
Though i have never used it so i personally do not know much about it, as per the answer above, [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database is also an option. You could look into that and see if that fits your needs as well.